# Runtime error while using string inside for each

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, runtime-error

In this code, I receive the following runtime error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
>   what():  basic_string::replace bash: line 1:  9471 Aborted
>   (core dumped)

As far as I am concerned, it means that I have manipulated the vector inside the for each loop, while I have not done that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


std::string replace(std::string text,
                  std::string find,
                  std::string replace)
{
    return(text.replace(text.find(find), find.length(), replace));
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> mylist={"col1","cell2","col3","cell4","col5"};

    for(const std::string item: mylist)
    {
        std::cout<<replace(item,"cell","item")<<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The exception is being thrown by `basic_string::replace`, not something of `vector`. Consider what `text.find(find)` returns when the string cannot be found.

Comment: Use a debugger! It will really help.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi could you introduce a debugger using Ubuntu and SublimeText3 ?

Comment: @barej I'm not using Ubuntu but I'm confident that you *will* find a debugger for whatever compiler you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to replace `cell` to `item` in a string `col1`. There is no such substring, so `text.find()` will return `string::npos` (usually `((size_t) -1)`, but implementation-specific). After that, `string::npos` is passed to `replace()` which causes exception.

Rewrite your function like this:

```
std::string replace(std::string text,
                std::string find,
                std::string replace)
{
    size_t idx = text.find(find);

    if(idx == std::string::npos)
        return(text);

    return(text.replace(idx, find.length(), replace));
}
```

Comment: @T.C. The function should not touch text bu return the replaced text.

Answer (score 3):

The `find()` function of `std::string` returns the `npos` position when the search string is not found. This `npos` position can not be used in `replace()` and gives this error.

Comment: `std::string::find` doesn't return iterator, it returns index!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a program that overcomes your runtime error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


std::string replaceText(std::string text,
    std::string f,
    std::string r)
{
    size_t found = text.find(f);
    if (found != std::string::npos)
        return(text.replace(found, f.length(), r));
    return text;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> mylist = { "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5" };

    for (const std::string item : mylist)
    {
        std::cout << replaceText(item, "cell", "item") << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The main part is:

```
int found = text.find(f);
if (found != std::string::npos)
    return(text.replace(text.find(f), f.length(), r));
return text;
```

Where a variable called `found` is used to check what to do when string is found. In case string is not found, I am returning the input text itself.

I have changed the function and variable names for better readability.

Comment: The second `text.find(f)` is unnecessary, and storing the return value of `find` in an `int` is problematic.

Comment: Thanks @T.C. I have made the changes.